# App Engine and receiving Mail

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working through the documents here:

```
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html#Receiving_Mail_in_Java
```

For receiving email. Below is my Servlet:

```
package mailserver;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.servlet.http.*; 

public class MailHandlerServlet extends HttpServlet { 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, 
                       HttpServletResponse resp) 
            throws IOException { 
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message =  null;
        try {
            message = new MimeMessage(session, req.getInputStream());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(message);
    }
}
```

My appengine-xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>myapp</application>
  <version>4</version>

<inbound-services>
  <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>

  <!--
    By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server.
    To allow App Engine to send multiple requests in parallel specify:

      <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  -->

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

</appengine-web-app>
```

And the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>MailHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>mailserver.MailHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MailHandlerServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/notification@myemail.appspotmail.com</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/notification@myemail.appspotmail.com</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

My first question, I haven't set up any sort of extra email address where it says:

Receive incoming email at string@appid.appspotmail.com addresses

I assume this is like a catchall and string can be whatever I like?

My next question is would the servlet show anything if it was working? At the moment I'm just getting `The requested URL /mailserver was not found on this server.`

Any help getting started would be great.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email messages are sent to your app as HTTP request (POST) generated by App Engine. `string@appid.appspotmail.com` is the general syntax. `string` is some you can choose, e.g. for specific url pattern of servlet mapping (routing to specific servlet) - in your case only `notification@myemail.appspotmail.com` will be processed by the MailHandlerServlet.

> The requested URL /mailserver was not found on this server.

I can't see a mapping for that URL in your code. The URL path is `/_ah/mail/` (`url-pattern`).

If the HTTP call / servlet operation was successful, you would get a HTTP status code 20X.